# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. when trying to install rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, makefile

SYS: Ubuntu 14.04
Ruby version:
    ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]
Gem version: 2.4.8

I can't say that I have rich experience on rails, but when I tried to deploy rails on my new computer, I can't even install rails.
This is the gem_make.out file
`/usr/local/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20151030-11581-1f0cbp1.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
* extconf.rb failed *
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.`

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/https.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mini_portile-0.6.2/lib/mini_portile.rb:3:in`'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:128:in`rescue in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:39:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:395:in`'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Since I have no way to use Openssl while make, I replaced the https source to http.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following to make sure you have the necessary libs:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev zlib1g-dev libgmp-dev libxml2-dev libssl-dev openssl
```

Comment: It seems no... I have already installed all the libs needed... but still no use... become confused...

Comment: Oui, je suis désolé, ça marche.

Comment: my system lack of one of the libs, and after I tried to install all of the libs, I didn't compile the ruby installation again. <br> So, after the installation, you should compile ruby again, be careful to execute every commande with sudo

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I found a way to solve, this is based on the solution of@matanco, mais his solution is not complete
`sudo apt-get install ruby-dev zlib1g-dev libgmp-dev libxml2-dev libssl-dev openssl`
after you execute this commande, you should compile you ruby installation again

`sudo sh ./configure

sudo make

sudo make install`

Answer (score -1):

Ruby code requires ssl native libraries and headers to be built.

This could solve your problem

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.